# Combine two buttons into one toggling button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, smarty

I have two buttons on my web page that are meant to show and hide a set of tools on the page. My goal is to combine them into one button that retains the toggling functionality, and changes what the button says depending on whether the tools are hidden/shown.

My code so far is:

```
{if $edit_page neq 'y'}
<style> .hidden-div{ display:none } </style>
<button id="show-bar" onclick="getElementById('bottom-bar').style.display = 'block'"> Show Page Tools </button>

<style> .hidden-div{ display:block } </style>
<button id="hide-bar" onclick="getElementById('bottom-bar').style.display = 'none'"> Hide Page Tools </button>
{/if}
```

How can I get these two buttons combined into one? Currently if the div is hidden, that button does nothing, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for such simple script. You could do this for example this way in pure JavaScript:

```
{assign var="edit_page" value="n"}

{if $edit_page neq 'y'}
<button id="show-bar" onclick="toggleButton(); return false;">Show Page Tools</button>
{/if}

<div id="bottom-bar" style="display: none;">
something
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleButton() 
    {
        element = document.getElementById('bottom-bar');

        if (element.style.display == 'none') {
            element.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('show-bar').innerHTML = 'Hide Page Tools';
        }
        else {
            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('show-bar').innerHTML = 'Show Page Tools';
        }


    }
</script>
```

Of course if you use jQuery for other things you could use it in this case but if you want to use it just for this functionality, you don't need to.

Comment: This is great. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Insert this on your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And the use the code on this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Dqsdc/

Comment: Thanks, I just came across this in my searches as well. Will let you know how it turns out.